# 4D vectors perpendicular to one another and to vector $(1, 1, 1, 1)$

Tags: vectors

How would I solve for vectors $u, v$, and $w \in \mathbb{R}^4$ when $u,v,w≠0$ and are perpendicular to one another and vector $(1, 1, 1, 1)$?

If I set them all up as dot products I still have so many unknowns so I don't know what to do or if I am on the right track.

Comment: You can use the dollar signs to input mathematical symbols. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: I think the Gram-Schmidt procedure would help here - it will still be tedious though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously it doesn't have a unique solution. Just because if $v$ is a solution then $\lambda v $ for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ is another.

Just try this step by step construction

First we build a vector perpendicular to $(1,1,1,1)$, in this way we obtain that a vector $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ must satisfy $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=0$ (the relation of orthogonality is given by the standard scalar product of $\mathbb{R}^4$. So we choose (for example) $(1,-1,0,0)$ as a solution of such "system". Now we have to find a third vector perpendicular to the other two, so let $(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)$ be such vector (obviously written over the standard base). It has to satisfy the two orthogonality relations given by:

\begin{cases}
y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4 =0 \\
y_1-y_2 =0
\end{cases}

We note $(0,0,1,-1)$ is a solution (advice: choose the most easy one - the solution with most zeroes to speed up calculation :) ). Then in this way you have to consider a system with three equation now, and find another solution. The four solutions are the vectors you need. Please note that we have chosen one solution from every set of solutions and this show that there are infinite way to build such set.

**Assuming you know GS** Even using Gram - Schmidt algorithm with a restriction to the norm of such vector we can't find an unique solution. The fact that leads you to infinite solution is that you have to choose a set of independent linear vector as starting point for the process.

Another way of visualizing such arbitrariness in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is to fix one vector and note that you in fact an hyperplane (a space) of solutions for the first vector. Then by considering the intersection of the orthogonal spaces of the first two vector you have another plane of solution (use grassman formula) and so on..

Comment: Note that GS transforms a basis into an othogonal basis. Thus the freedom in GS is in chosing the remaining three basis vectors. After that, GS leaves no "choices".

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that there are infinitely many solutions of these vectors. If you are searching for a solution, it is easy. Let $u=(1,-1,0,0)$, then $u\cdot(1,1,1,1)=0$. Suppose that $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4),w=(w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4)$ and now easily use dot product.

Comment: you can also see $v=(0,0,1,-1)^T$ will work with $u^T v = 0 = (1,1,1,1)v$, so only one more system for $w$-

Comment: yes, you are completely right@AlexR

Comment: could you please let me add it to this solution@AlexR

Comment: Of course you may improve it. Note that I have already written an answer with a matching $w$.

Comment: your answer is enough

Answer (score 1):

In general Gram-Schmidt is the way to go to find orthogonal (or even orthonormal) bases. In this special case we can simplify things a lot though.

Let $v_1=(1,1,1,1)$, our goal is to find a basis $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}$ of $\mathbb R^4$ with the $v_i$ pairwise orthogonal.

The way to do this is step by step, so you look for $v_2$ perpendicular to $v_1$ first, which can be found as $v_2=(1,-1,0,0)$ easily. Now you need $v_3$ to be perpendicular to both $v_1$ and $v_2$. This is still easy, as $v_3=(0,0,1,-1)$ does the job.

To find the last vector we could guess, use Gram-Schmidt, solve the system of equations given by the dot product, or use the cross-product on $\mathbb R^4$:
\begin{align}
v_1\times v_2\times v_3 &=
\left|\matrix{\mathbf e_1 & \mathbf e_2 & \mathbf e_3 & \mathbf e_4\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1
}\right|
=
-
\left|\matrix{\mathbf e_1 & \mathbf e_2 & \mathbf e_4\\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 0 \\
}\right|
-
\left|\matrix{\mathbf e_1 & \mathbf e_2 & \mathbf e_3 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 0\\
}\right|
\\&= -(\mathbf e_2-\mathbf e_4-\mathbf e_4+\mathbf e_1)-(\mathbf e_2-\mathbf e_3-\mathbf e_3+\mathbf e_1)
\\&= (-2, -2, 2, 2)
\end{align}
So $v_4=(-1,-1,1,1)$ does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Chose $u = (1,-1,0,0)^T$ and $v=(0,0,1,-1)^T$. Let $e=(1,1,1,1)^T$. We see that
$$u^T e = u^T v = v^T e = 0$$
so we need to find $w$ such that
$$\begin{cases}w^T u = w_1 - w_2 = 0\\w^T v = w_3-w_4 = 0\\w^T e = w_1+w_2+w_3+w_4 = 0\end{cases}$$
This gives us $w_1 = w_2, w_3 = w_4$ and $2(w_1 + w_3) = 0$ thus
$$w = (1,1,-1,-1)^T$$
is a nice solution.